# How do I download JSON file of reviews of this page from its network panel?

Tags: json, web-scraping, inspect, review

Inspect page-Network panel of a product:
[image: Inspect page-Network panel of a product]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask an appropriate question. You will not get very many (or any at all) solutions by simply posting a link to a photo. I am assuming you are using python since you asked a beautifulsoup question a few days ago. There are plenty of solutions that describe this process by a simple google search. But if you post the url and what data you are after, I may be able to help.

Comment: @chitown88 hi thanks for response. URL - https://www.thebodyshop.com/en-us/body/body-butter/olive-body-butter/p/p000016 Data - number of reviews. in my last post, somebody helped me extracting that but i wanted to know how did he find out the JSON file linked with bazaarvoice reviews from network panel. that is my question here.

Comment: ah ok. It just takes a little investigative work. You have to browse around and see if you find the data returned in a json format. Sometimes it's there, sometimes it's not. But you'd look exactly where you highlighted in the photo you posted.